# IntelliJ, deploying on localhost without restart tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

For some special reason, my webapp2 must be deployed after webapp1. I know in IntelliJ, I can configure local deployment with two webapps (2 war files), but it start up in random order and break my apps. 
Currently I have to manually start up tomcat (using command line), then go to the manager page (on localhost) and upload my war files. Webapp1 is stable, so most of the time, I have to change webapp2 and upload it and debug. I'm looking for a way that I can set up deployment for webapp2 directly in IntelliJ without restarting tomcat (the one I started from cmdline, with webapp1 running on it). Does one exist? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should configure IDEA to perform deployment and [update](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html) of both the artifacts. Just use the Local Tomcat configuration.

IDEA has a configuration for artifacts deployment order.